# Making transparent view over semitransparent view (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make one transparent rectangle view over one semitransparent rectangle view.

Desired:

┌──────────────┐
│　　　　　　　　　　│
│　┌─────────┐　│
│　│transparent　 │　│
│　└─────────┘　│
│ 50% transparent　　│
└──────────────┘

Actual:

┌────────────────┐
│　　　　　　　　 　　　│
│　┌───────────┐　│
│　│50% transparent　│　│
│　└───────────┘　│
│ 50% transparent 　　　│
└────────────────┘

Code:

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_half_shade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overlay_textguide"        
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#80FFFFFF" /> // 50% transparent

<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_transparent"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overlay_textguide"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/focus_thumbnail_slide" /> // custom drawable: transparent rectangle with stroke
```

I guess that the whole transparency of the center region considers transparencies of both two overlapped boxes; resulting 50% transparency there. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried -  < android:alpha="0" > or  < android:background="#00FFFFFF" > in second view.

Comment: have to see my post it will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this and get your expected output

**inner_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp" android:color="#80B22222" />
</shape>
```

**in your xml layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_half_shade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overlay_textguide"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/inner_shape">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hierarchy like this

```
  <RelativeLayout> 

    <FrameLayout ....
           alpha =0.5/>

     <FrameLayout ....
           gravity=center
           alpha =0.9/>// decide your transperany 
  </RelativeLayout>
```